# Какой индекс передать в метод splice для удаления массива в цикле forEach?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const minus = document.querySelectorAll('.minus');
minus.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        const itemProduct = menu.products[parseInt(e.target.dataset.id)];
        const haveOrder = menu.orders.some((itemOrder) => {
            if (itemOrder.name === itemProduct.name) {
                if (itemOrder.count === 1) {
                    menu.orders.splice(itemOrder, 1);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    itemOrder.count -= 1;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
        showOrders();
    })
});
```

Comment: зачем вам переменная `haveOrder`? вы ее не используете. `itemOrder` - это объект, а не число. Посмотрите для начала документацию по методу `splice` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: Да это так не обратил внимание! Можете подсказать какой параметр передать чтобы потом удалился именно этот элемент с массив а не с начало и или с конца!

Comment: Я посмотрел уже не помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `splice` принимает в качестве аргументов - индекс, с которого будут удалены элементы ( включительно ), кол-во элементов, которые нужно удалить и элементы, которые заменят удаленные. Поэтому что бы удалить конкретный элемент из массива, нужно написать так

```
item.splice(index, 1);
```

В вашем случае, вы все это делает в метод `some`, который вторым параметром возвращает индекс текущего элемента, поэтому

```
items.some((item, index) => {
   items.splice(index, 1);

});
```

**NOTE**

Я бы не советовал вам мутировать ( изменять ) массив прямо внутри цикла обхода этого массива. Большая вероятность, что это может привести к багам и не очевидному поведению. 
Лучше сделать так, на вскидку:

```
    const haveOrder = menu.orders.some((itemOrder) => {
        if (itemOrder.name === itemProduct.name) {
            if (itemOrder.count === 1) {
                menu.orders.splice(itemOrder, 1);
                return true;
            } else {
                itemOrder.count -= 1;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Заменить на

```
   const orderIndex = menu.orders.findIndex(itemOrder =>
     itemOrder.name === itemProduct.name
   );
   if (orderIndex >= 0) {
     const order = menu.orders[orderIndex];
     order.count -= 1;
     if (order.count === 0) {
       menu.orders.splice(orderIndex, 1);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Я вам очень благодарен)))